# Using the facebook popup design in my app

Tags: css, facebook, popup, facebook-apps

I am developing a Facebook App and I want use the exact design (style) that facebook has, to show a post - picture, link, status etc. So for example I show a link to a post on the wall that has a picture in it and when the user wants to see details about it, a popup shows all info (picture, likes, comments etc) exactly how Facebook shows it if you would click the picture in your wall. My question is: am I allowed to copy the exact design of the pop up, or is there a way I can do this by just calling a function with the parameter being the post id?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea - you can recreate their UI.  Checkout this answer I gave a little while back - it might be useful to you.
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8912265/558021
The only issue with recreating their UI (IMO) is to start [altering their brands](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php).